# Realm with SwiftUI Returning List<ShoppingItem>

Tags: swiftui, realm

I am using Realm with SwiftUI and creating a parent-child relationship. I am creating the following property so it can return List. The reason, I am creating a property is because I want to perform filter and sort on it, which I will do later.

```
 var items: List<ShoppingItem> {
        shoppingList.items
    }
```

I get a weird error message:

[image]

Comment: It's telling you that it got 1, but it's expecting more. Have you read the entire error message? if so, please share it.

Comment: Why are you creating another property to return a List property? Why not just return the List itself? e.g. let shoppingList = someObject.shoppingList or let myList = someObject.shoppingList.items? Also, please include errors as text in questions. Images are not searchable so future readers may not be able to locate it. We also cannot see the complete error.

Comment: For future readers; this issue is not an issue with Swift but only with SwiftUI (just for clarity in case you overlooked the SwiftUI tag)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It conflicts with `SwiftUI.List`, so you need to add module explicitly

```
var items: RealmSwift.List<ShoppingItem>
```