# Realm List Error (Swift): Generic type 'List' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)

Tags: swiftui, realm, realm-list

I'm following the MongoDB Realm documentation and in one example I get the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Context: 
`Realm: 10.26.0` 
`RealmDatabase: 11.17.0`

Realm documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/examples/define-a-realm-object-model/#std-label-ios-define-a-to-one-relationship-property

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't indicate your coding platform but if it's SwiftUI, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72244891/realm-with-swiftui-returning-listshoppingitem/72245446#72245446) please let us know either way and add a tag to your question with your platform. Also, in future questions, please include the actual code, not a picture or link; see [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @Jay: Yes, that solved the problem. Thanks very much! I'll take your advice into account in the future, thanks for the nice tip. Should I leave the question as it is or close it?

Comment: Glad to help. It's fine as is and references the answer. Happy coding!